# From the extension is it possible to capture a site's CSP programmatically on page load?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm building a Chrome extension that alters the DOM on sites. I want to access a site's content security policy on page load (if it exists) to know if the extension would work or not based on the CSP directives.

Currently the only way I'm able to read a site's CSP is to create an event listener for `securitypolicyviolation` and wait for an error to occur. If an error is thrown, that's when I'm able to see what the directives are. This leads to bad UX.

What I'm hoping to do is access the CSP beforehand so no error is thrown.

Comment: You could look into making a HEAD ajax request to some resource on the page, or maybe the page itself.  When you get the response, look in the headers for the content security policy.

Comment: hmm...good suggestion. let me see if I can make something work with that.

Comment: CSP could be delivered not only via HTTP header, so do not forget to check `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="...">`

Comment: @granty I wasn't successful going this route unfortunately. Using `document.getElementsByTagName('meta')` returned a whole lot of tags but none has the `http-equiv` for the CSP. But in my search I'm seeing that my issue isn't anything unique. I'm going to give using `XMLHttpRequest()` a try. Seems like people are having luck with that.

Comment: If you have a background script or don't mind adding one, you can read the CSP header in chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived event.

Comment: @wOxxOm oh that's another great idea. But it looks like I'll need to add `webRequest` to the manifest permissions. Trying to not add anything new to the manifest so that the user won't have to reauthorize. But definitely looks like a great solution.

Comment: webRequest doesn't add any warnings, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings).

Comment: Check `document.getElementsByTagName('meta')` on those sites: https://www.liputan6.com/, http://126.com/, https://lichess.org/, https://www.dafont.com/fr/, https://www.leroymerlin.fr/. The last one has 2 CSPs - via <meta> and via HTTP-header and these are completely different. Although my business is to crow, dawn is the sun's business :)